# On IsSimple() in Magma.

Tags: finite-groups, magma-cas

It is known that $S_{11}$ is a Atlas group and is not a simple group. In Magma,

> IsSimple(ATLASGroup("S11"));
>
> > Runtime error in 'IsSimple': Bad argument types
> >     Argument types given: GrpAtlas

We want to know how to avoid this error in Magma.

Comment: You should convert your Atlas Group into a Matrix Group or a Permutation Group using a key. Read the instructions in the Atlas Group part of the Handbook.

Comment: @xarles I'm a freshman for Magma. Can you give me a example?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magma, the answer to ATLASGroup("S11") is not a Permutation Group or a Matrix Group, but an element of a different type, and you cannot ask it if it is simple.
You need to convert it to an actual group, by using the keys.

It is described in [the documentation.](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/761)

In your case you can do:

> K:=MatRepKeys(ATLASGroup("S11"));
>
> G:=MatrixGroup(K[1]);
>
> IsSimple(G);

First you get the list of keys. There is only one. Then you use the key to get a Matrix Group G. Then you ask what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the file :  ..\Magma\libs/data/Atlas/alt_mrep.ind

Comment: @Qin You can use Magma via the calculator in the web: